# iOS - Tabbed aplication with table view and subview

Tags: uitableview, subview, tabbed-view

I have one problem. in my app (it is tabbed style), I have one viewcontroller with some text and second with table view (RSS reader). When I have just the RSS and it is set to single view app, subview form rss works, but when I set up the tabbed app and click to some post in table view, subview didnt show up... Can anybody help me please?

Here are my codes:

AppDelegate.h

```
         #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MWFeedParserAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {

    UIWindow *window;
    UINavigationController *navigationController;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIWindow *window;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UINavigationController *navigationController;

@end
```

AppDelegate.m

```
#import "MWFeedParserAppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController1.h"
#import "RootViewController.h"

@implementation MWFeedParserAppDelegate

@synthesize window;
@synthesize navigationController;

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Application lifecycle

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    // Override point for customization after app launch
    UITabBarController *tbc = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

    ViewController1 *vc1 = [[ViewController1 alloc]init];
    RootViewController *vc2 = [[RootViewController alloc]init];

    [vc1.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Tab1"];
    [vc2.tabBarItem setTitle:@"Tab2"];

    [tbc setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, nil]];
    [window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
    [window makeKeyAndVisible];
    [window setRootViewController:tbc];
    return YES;
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {
    // Save data if appropriate
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark Memory management

- (void)dealloc {
    [navigationController release];
    [window release];
    [super dealloc];
}


@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the dealloc, I see you are not using arc.
You have some memory leaks; be sure to release `vc1` and `vc2` in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`, the tab bar controller will retain them.

You probably don't need `navigationController` property, recommend you delete that until you know you'll need it.

I think you'll want to add your RSS view (vc2?) to a nav controller before adding to the tab bar controller like this:

```
[tbc setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc2] autorelease], nil]];
```

And delete this line:

```
[window addSubview:[navigationController view]];
```

Best of luck!!

**edit** Spelled out a tad more:

```
ViewController1 *vc1 = [[[ViewController1 alloc] init] autorelease];
RootViewController *vc2 = [[[RootViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UINavigationController *navController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:vc2] autorelease];
UITabBarController *tbc = [[[UITabBarController alloc] init] autorelease];
[tbc setViewControllers:@[vc1, navController]];
[window makeKeyAndVisible];
[window setRootViewController:tbc];
```